# Commit Changes are shown from automatic changes. How can I only see changes I made?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, blazor

I created an `Blazor WebAssembly App`. I set the Authentication option to `Individual User Accounts -> Store user accounts in-app` and I put a check mark at `Configure for HTTPS`, `ASP.NET Core hosted` and `Progressive Web Application`

[image]

I added a few .razor components, too.

I uploaded this Project to `Azure DevOps Repos`

[image]

Now when I clone this project I receive a lot of changes-notification. It gets even more changes when I build this project. I noticed that most of those changes are happening because the path changed in those files.

[image]

Is it possible to make it so I only see changes I really made? Like when I add, change or remove a file by myself?

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: I added *.g.cs to my .gitignore but I still see those files from that screenshot

Comment: I created a sample to test, the `*.g.cs` works fine on my side. Have you restart you VS? And are those `*.g.cs` files are all in your solution folder?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a .gitignore file to you project. I would recommend https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore so that specific files, e.g. compiled files - or in the case of blazor generated files, which are indicated by *.g.cs - are not part of the repository.